# Redmine and SVN - Problems installing pam_mysql

Tags: mysql, svn, debian, redmine, pam

I followed the instructions described [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_to_handle_SVN_repositories_creation_and_access_control_with_Redmine) but then when it says

```
./configure --with-openssl
```

onto the "**pam_mysql-0.7RC1**" it says

```
checking if the second argument of pam_conv.conv() takes const pointer... no
configure: error: Your system doesn't appear to be configured to use PAM. Perhaps you need to specify the correct location where the PAM modules reside.
```

in my shell so i am wondering how to fix this. Using Debian 3.2.46-1 x64

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to install a newer version of libpam-dev (or libpam0g-dev)

```
sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev
```

I just tried libpam0g-dev version 1.1.3-7.1 on my Debian 7.0(i386) and it configured fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of future readers, the following command fixed mine.

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-mysql-bg libpam-mysql
```